# M2 Observer Events

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I'm doing migration from M1 to M2 of some custom code.

I'm trying to use these events for observers, every observer file has die(); string to check if observer is working but nothing happens.

> controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling
>
> controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping
>
> controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShippingMethod
>
> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder
>
> checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after

Do these events are correct for M2? Because when I'm using `sales_order_save_after` it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for all available events in Magento 2.0 and 2.2. It may help you.

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/